# Google sheet - lock range if date has passed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a use case where I need a row (columns A - E) to be locked, if the date in column A of the row has passed. If the date is blank / today / future, the user with editor permission should be able to edit.

I have tried scripts for similar requirements from the internet but none are working. Here is one such script that ought to work but it is locking all rows, irrespective if the date is in the past/today/future. Can you please suggest the changes to be made to the script to make it work for my requirement? Thanks.

[Sample GS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jjurs7lBu2-tUyiHnDi0qC4epIFgB0Mq5en3VfNTTfM/edit?usp=sharing)

```
/**
 * Protect Rows Below Todays Date on ALL Sheets in the File
 * To protect rows of older data
 * Author: Mr Shane
 * Version: 2023-02-20-01
 ⇨ For: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/202312124
 */

function protectRowsEverySh() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    let sheet = sheets[i];

    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    let startRow = null;
    // Find the first row with a date that is NOT today's date
    for (let j = 2; j <= lastRow && startRow === null; j++ ) {
      let date = sheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue();
      if (date && date < today) {
        startRow = j;
      }
    }
    // If no row was found, skip to the next sheet
    if (startRow === null) {
      continue;
    }
    // Remove the existing (old) RANGE protections
    const oldprotections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    oldprotections.forEach(oldprotection => {
      if (oldprotection && oldprotection.canEdit()) {
        oldprotection.remove();
      }
    });
    // Protect all rows starting from the first row that has a date that is NOT today's date.
    const range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow - startRow+1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    const newprotection = range.protect().setDescription('Protected Rows');
    const me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    newprotection.addEditor(me);
    newprotection.removeEditors(newprotection.getEditors());
    if (newprotection.canDomainEdit()) {
      newprotection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current script, at `const range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow - startRow+1, sheet.getLastColumn());` and `const newprotection = range.protect().setDescription('Protected Rows');`, all rows of columns A to E are protected. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, your showing script is modified. And, the rows of columns A to E are protected by the protect() method of Class Rnage.

```js
function protectRowsEverySh() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  // I modified the below script.
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).forEach(p => p.remove());
    const values = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    values.forEach(([a], i) => {
      if (a !== "" && a instanceof Date && a.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) < today) {
        const newprotection = sheet.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 5).protect().setDescription('Protected Rows');
        const me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
        newprotection.addEditor(me);
        newprotection.removeEditors(newprotection.getEditors());
        if (newprotection.canDomainEdit()) {
          newprotection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of column A are checked. When the checked value is before today's date, the rows of columns A to E are protected.
- In this case, each row is protected by `protect` method. So, I'm worried that when the number of rows is large, the process cost might be high. So, I proposed another approach as follows.

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, your showing script is modified using Sheets API. And, the rows of columns A to E are protected by `addProtectedRange` of the method of batchRequests of Sheets API. So, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function protectRowsEverySh2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  // I modified the below script.
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const requests1 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, { fields: "sheets(protectedRanges(protectedRangeId))" }).sheets.flatMap(s => s.protectedRanges ? s.protectedRanges.map(({ protectedRangeId }) => ({ deleteProtectedRange: { protectedRangeId } })) : []);
  const requests2 = sheets.flatMap(sheet => {
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    if (lastRow <= 1) {
      return [];
    }
    const values = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow).getValues();
    const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
    return values.reduce((ar, [a], i) => {
      if (a !== "" && a instanceof Date && a.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) < today) {
        ar.push({ addProtectedRange: { protectedRange: { description: 'Protected Rows', range: { sheetId, startRowIndex: i + 1, endRowIndex: i + 2, startColumnIndex: 0, endColumnIndex: 5 }, editors: { users: [Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()], domainUsersCanEdit: false } } } });
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
  });
  const requests = [...requests1, ...requests2];
  if (requests.length == 0) return;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ssId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of column A are checked. When the checked value is before today's date, the rows of columns A to E are protected using Sheets API.

#### Note:

- From your showing script, all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet are used. Please be careful about this.
- When I tested the above-modified scripts to your provided Spreadsheet, no error occurred. When you change the Spreadsheet, those modified scripts might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [protect()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AddProtectedRangeRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addprotectedrangerequest)